# Help with understanding the method of MBD & MBD-NL

Tags: density-functional-theory, molecular-dynamics, computational-chemistry

I am having a hard time understanding the steps of Tkatchenko's method of many-body dispersion (MBD) and nonlocal many-body dispersion (MBD-NL).

I would greatly appreciate a detailed & clear explanation of both methods and how MBD is extended into the MBD-NL.

Much Thnx to anyone willing to help :)

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum!

Comment: Have checked out this other question? it may help: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2344/how-does-mbd-mbd-nl-differ-from-dft-ts

Comment: Hi @KristofBal , I appreciate your comment.
I already saw the question and answer you referred me to, and although it was very useful for understanding TS and MBD, I felt that the explanation about how to expand MBD into MBD-NL was not sufficient. 
If anyone help me to clarify what is the correction that needs to be done in order to achieve the non-local term? It doesn't seem as simple as "just adding a correction term".
I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks! :)